# Converting Base64 to Hex confusion

Tags: base64, hex, radix

I was working on a problem for converting base64 to hex and the problem prompt said as an example:

> `3q2+7w==` should produce `deadbeef`

But if I do that manually, using the base64 digit set `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/` I get:

```
3 110111
q 101010
2 110110
+ 111110
7 111011
w 110000
```

As a binary string:

```
110111 101010 110110 111110 111011 110000
```

grouped into fours:

```
1101 1110 1010 1101 1011 1110 1110 1111 0000
```

to hex

```
d e a d b e e f 0
```

So shouldn't it be `deadbeef0` and not `deadbeef`? Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base64 is meant to encode bytes (8 bit).

Your base64 string has 6 characters plus 2 padding chars (`=`), so you could theoretically encode 6*6bits = 36 bits, which would equal 9 4bit hex numbers. But in fact you must think in bytes and then you only have 4 bytes (32 bits) of significant information. The remaining 4 bits (the extra '0') must be ignored.

You can calculate the number of insignificant bits as:

```
y : insignificant bits
x : number of base64 characters (without padding)

y = (x*6) mod 8
```

So in your case:

```
y = (6*6) mod 8 = 4
```

So you have 4 insignificant bit on the end that you need to ignore.